# How to calculate gas fees to deploy smart contract? (on Hardhat OR Truffle)

Tags: hardhat

How to calculate gas fees to deploy smart contract on Hardhat OR Truffle

Comment: See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35539/what-is-the-real-price-of-deploying-a-contract-on-the-mainnet/37898. Answers explain how to calculate gas for deployment on mainnet. Is it what you wanted to know? Or do you want to know specifically a truffle/hardhat command for this?

Comment: I think he's looking specifically for a command in hardhat/truffle to do this